# Anterior pelvic tilt. If not abs or glutes, what else may be weak?

Tags: posture

I believe I have reasonably strong abs and glutes (I hip thrust a pretty decent weight, I think). Despite that, my anterior pelvic tilt is quite conspicuous. What else may be the problem? I'm not sure it's related, but I also kind of have trouble keeping my back straight when sitting (I *can* do it but only with willpower). Is there some correctional exercise I should try?

Comment: Do you have chronic low back pain?

Comment: Are you sure you have APT? did you get it diagnosed by a doctor or just the internet?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I don't

Comment: @Luciano it wasn't diagnosed but I can see it with my own eyes

Comment: Stiff hip flexors may be the thing, btw. But they are stretched at least as I hip thrust and squat every three days

Comment: Then what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Jeff said APT happens because of stiff hips

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Again, what problem are you trying to solve? If it isn’t causing you pain, it isn’t interfering with your exercise or any other part of your life, what’s the problem?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov it's ugly and unhealthy, may cause problems down the road. Maybe it already has and I just haven't attributed it to the APT yet. You're basically asking, "Why does good posture matter?"

Comment: Sounds much more like you’ve been told it’s really bad by people who don’t know what they’re talking about. Did Jeff tell you APT was going to cause you problems in the future?

Answer (score 2):

The best explanation to your question is to decide whether or not anterior pelvic tilt/posture **is** a problem. The answer is, it probably **does not**.

Most movement and posture has no inherent positive or negative.  Much of this depends on your body's limb length, musculature, and body composition. No two people have the same posture.  There is also no strong answer to what a *normal* posture looks like. Finally, there's not any strong evidence linking anyone's posture to having negative outcomes for overall health.

A good summary of some posture information can be found from [Jeff Nippard's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUSyMqDUkv8) about this topic.

Adjacently, I would recommend reading [this article from Barbell Medicine](https://www.barbellmedicine.com/blog/pain-and-movement-caught-in-an-endless-loop-of-misinformation/) about pain and movement that also discusses the cycle of poor communication that bad movements are the cause of pain and that becomes a cyclic piece of misinformation.  Mainly, movement is complicated and probably not strongly linked to 'poor movements'.